# RSS feed problem

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm using feed aggregator to receive RSS feeds, but when I click to update the item it gives me these errors:

```
The feed from News seems to be broken, because of error "Mismatched tag" on line 27.
```

and

```
The feed from News seems to be broken, because of error "XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED" on line 28.
```

My feed URL is http://www.sakaaltimes.com/RSS.htm

I run the cron.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i have encountered the same issue may times. The best way to evade from such a error is to take the feeds one by one. 
I mean you can take the feed http://www.sakaaltimes.com/RSS/nation.xml from http://www.sakaaltimes.com/RSS.htm and one by one in this fashion.
The feed module by itself is a scrapper so when ever a html tag mismatch occurs it will lead to a error. So have a try at the subfeeds in your given URL.